# Anaconda installed but No module named 'conda' after installing flake8

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor, miniconda, flake8

While trying to install atom-lint package in Atom editor I somehow corrupted my conda installation.

I did the following things that might have caused the issue:

- Installed a python dependency `Flake8` using conda install.
- Messed around with Atom Init Script (I can provide more info if needed)

After I did these things I encountered the following problem:

If I run `conda` I get

```
$ conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

Strangely enough if I run `python` in my command line anaconda still seems to be installed an working.

```
$ python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 23 2018, 14:07:42)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I have also noticed that the Python3 bin has disappeared from the conda environment folder `~/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin/`

This is very strange and I thought might be related.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: python can run without anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making a backup copy of the miniconda3/envs folder, reinstalling miniconda and copying the environment back in. It works now, not sure what caused the issue.